# TestCafe: Is there any limitations to the length of the URL accessed by .navigateTo method?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, browser-automation

In a certain scenario, the test freezes when the page accessed has an url with more than 4k characters.
In dev tools console I'm getting some errors (500) related to some .js files from testcafe, like task.js.
If I split the url to less than 3k characters, it works. Can this be changed from some config files ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are limits.  And unfortunately there not even standard.

Comment: Thank you for response. So there is no solution from testcafe side on scenarios like this, only from the app urls mechanism if it s possible

Answer (score 5):

The client-server messaging device (based on https://github.com/inikulin/replicator) in TestCafe imposes a ~65K character limit. This limit is not configurable. Even taking into account the maximum service information size (several hundred bytes), this is clearly more than the limitation that you encountered. I assume you are dealing with browser limitations ([What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/)).